# When to use a custom context path than root context in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, spring-boot

Is there any advantage using a custom context-path instead of root context for Spring Boot applications?

Many microservices are accessed without a custom context-path in the url, and another ones does not.

As Spring Boot initially loads only one web container we would not have the same behavior that a Tomcat offers,  when we have many web applications running into the same http port.

What are differences for both cases in this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a custom context path makes your service more reusable. If you choose the default context "/" then you are more likely to have a collision with another service that attempts to use the context as compared to a custom one. Not to mention, it makes it more human readable and intuitive as to what the service is for (IMO).

Basically you stated it yourself. If you intend to run multiple services on the same physical server, you would have to alter the Tomcat port for each Spring Boot application (assuming you are using embedded Tomcat). If you were not using embedded tomcat, you would have even more fun by having multiple installations of Tomcat on the same server, each with a different port.

Granted, you could make the decision that you will run only one application per physical server and use DNS to provide a nice URL path, that would be mapped to a specific server IP. That would avoid the conflict, but seems very wasteful of resources and is harder to maintain.

Comment: When we use Spring Boot each application will have your own port,  so I do not have the possibility of sharing this port with other applications.  The matter here is to use a root or context path to be more reusable theorically.

Comment: Yes, I think I answered that, with the issue of port just one aspect of the answer. I also think the fact that you will always have a different port is 'convenient' and removes that as a concern. But by leaving the default context, you now have no choice but have a separate port and therefore are in fact less reusable, do you agree?

Comment: Sorry,  but up to now it is not clear for me if you prefer to have a root path or a custom context-path.  I agree that who is using the url is clearer seeing the context name in there that just one port number instead,  but we  also have the service name in the url that really helps.

Comment: I would always have a unique context. And you are right, you will have a service name, which commonly will be a noun for some entity/object. So, having the context even helps that 'read well' /myapp/myservice/myserviceaction .

Comment: By the way...Spring Boot rocks, don't you think?

Comment: I think so. Nothing is gonna be the same after Spring Boot!